# Retrieve json store keys in a predetermined order in kivy?

Tags: python, json, kivy

Im working on a program using kivy and python, and i will be saving some data to a json file like say 'items.json'.
The thing is i intend to retrieve the data from the store and use them to form 
a list of buttons in my app. here is an example.

```
store = JsonStore('items.json')
store.put('infinix', name = 'infinix', category = 'gadgets')
store.put('wrist watch', name = 'wrist watch', category = 'outfits')
store.put('t-shirt', name = 't-shirt', category = 'outfits')
```

this works well. But my problem is in retrieving the data.
i would like to get them in the same order i entered the data into the store.
for example if i do

```
store.keys()
```

i would like it to return

```
['infinix', 'wrist watch', 't-shirt']
```

which is the same order i entered the data.

currently whenever i try to retrieve the data, the order is mixed up.
is there a way to achieve what i need?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are *any* of the storage engines ordered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option would seem to be just adding an extra storage key containing a list of your items in the correct order. You can then just check this first, and load them in that order.

Comment: inclement. Really appreciate the help so far. But can you please give an example code to demonstrate this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Oaks-view `store.put('key_order', value=['infinix', 'wrist watch', 't-shirt'])` I think that what he means